# I want to use regular expression for returning index in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to get index from array.

For example:

```
s = "arr[2]"
```

I want to use regular expression for returning index[2]

Updated!
I want also to return the name of array (arr)

Answer (score 3):

This should do it the regex way! (Find all possible numbers between square brackets `[]`

```
def get_idx(s):
    m = re.search(r"\[([-?a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\]", s)
    return m.group(1)
```

Then you can test it as

```
print(get_idx("arr[2]"))
#2
print(get_idx("arr[24]"))
#24
print(get_idx("arr[245]"))
#245
print(get_idx("arr[-2]"))
#-2
print(get_idx("arr2[-2]"))
#-2
print(get_idx("arr2[hex]"))
#hex
```

In order to get the name of the array, you can do

```
def get_name(s):
    m = re.search(r"(.*)\[.*", s)
    return m.group(1)
```

Then you can test it as

```
import re

def get_name(s):
    m = re.search(r"(.*)\[.*", s)
    return m.group(1)

print(get_name("arr[2]"))
#arr
print(get_name("arr[24]"))
#arr
print(get_name("arr[245]"))
#arr
print(get_name("arr[-2]"))
#arr
print(get_name("arr2[-2]"))
#arr2
```

Comment: what if arr[-1] ?

Comment: Could you explain ? If I want to return the name of array  then what is it regex ? @Devesh Kumar Singh

Comment: I have updated my answer for that case @Alex! Please check and consider accepting the answer if it works :)

Comment: Could you explain what to do ? For example, If index is hex. How to change it ? @ Devesh Kumar Singh

Comment: I didn't understand your question, you mean `arr[hex]` ? If yes, I updated my answer for that

Comment: Why do we need "-?" and "_" ? @ Devesh Kumar Singh

Comment: Since indexes can be negative we need a -? And an index variable can have underscore due to snake case eg var_name so we have  _  Makes sense @Alex?

Answer (score 0):

There is way without `regex`

```
s[s.find("[")+1:s.find("]")]
```

If you want to use `regex`, you can use the following:

```
import re
re.search(r'\[(.*?)\]',s).group(1)
```

In both the methods output is as following:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
re.search("\[(-?\d+)\]", s).group(1)
```

For more on Regex go through this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: I have edited it now. Thanks for correcting me. Since in Python indexing can even be negative, I have edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The following is more than enough given your example:

```python
import re
re.search(r"(.*)\[(.*)\]", s).groups()
```

Where `s` is your string and `.groups()` tells Python to return the groups found in the parentheses `()` as a tuple `(<group1>, <group2>)`. To break it down:

- `.` = any non-newline character
- `*` = 0 or more times
- `()` = delimit the group of characters to be extracted, otherwise the square brackets will be returned as well
- `\[` and `\]` = the square brackets need to be escaped with `\` because they are regex special characters (read more about escapes [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax))

To put it together: *Extract any group of 0 or more non-newline characters found before a square bracket `[`, and extract and group of 0 or more non-newline characters that can be found between two square brackets `[` and `]`.* The other solutions also utilize the special character `?` to make the match non-greedy, but it isn't necessary in your example as there is only one set of square brackets.

Besides being terser than the other solutions, it also deals with special cases better, and will extract everything found before or within the brackets, i.e. digits, `+` and `-`, and any indices given as variable names, such as `x`:

```python
re.search(r"(.*)\[(.*)\]", "arr[23]").groups()
## ('arr', '23')

re.search(r"(.*)\[(.*)\]", "arr[-23]").groups()
## ('arr', '-23')

re.search(r"(.*)\[(.*)\]", "arr[+23]").groups()
## ('arr', '+23')

re.search(r"(.*)\[(.*)\]", "arr-2[23]").groups()
## ('arr-2', '23')

re.search(r"(.*)\[(.*)\]", "arr[x]").groups()
## ('arr', 'x')

re.search(r"(.*)\[(.*)\]", "arr[FF00EE88]").groups()
## ('arr', 'FF00EE88')
```

Also, don't forget that strings are being returned, so you'll need to coerce your array indices (the second value in the returned tuple) into integers with `int` if that's what you need.